# Node js: how to get the path to a packge

Tags: node.js

I am writing a node package and I need to copy some files that are included in the package. But I can't find a way to get the path to the npm package.
How can I get it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

have you looked at `__dirname`? Here are the docs: http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname

You can use the `__dirname` variable from a module to derive the location of other packages.